# Chain of callbacks in twisted incorrectly repeats the last callback

Tags: python, twisted

I'm playing around with twisted and I'm trying to create a simple master server which distributes a list of unit tests to its slaves. The following code works, but my output is weird. Instead of executing each of the n tests, the slave is executing the last unit test n times.

I'm using twisted's built in amp protocol. Here is the relevant code:

```
class Master(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tests = [
            "test1",
            "tests2",
            ... etc
        ]

    def serve(self):
        self.factory = MasterFactory()
        reactor.listenTCP(1234, self.factory)
        d = threads.deferToThread(self.get_cmd)
        d.addCallback(lambda ign: self.run_test())
        print 'Serving on port 1234'

    def get_cmd(self):
        return raw_input('> ')

    def run_test(self):
        while True:
            for slave in self.factory.slaves.values():
                if self.tests == []:
                    break
                slave.tests.append(self.tests.pop(0))
            if self.tests == []:
                break

        for slave in self.factory.slaves.values():
            self.construct_list(slave)

    def construct_list(self, slave):
        d = defer.Deferred()
        for test in slave.tests:
            d.addCallback(lambda ign:
                slave.protocol.callRemote(commands.RunCmd, cmd="python setup.py trial -s " + test))
            d.addCallback(self.cmd_response)
        d.callback(None)

    def cmd_response(self, response):
        print response['output']
        return None


def main():
    m = Master()
    m.serve()
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: As an aside, the logic in `run_test` can be simplified using `itertools.cycle`. I would do something like `for test, slave in zip(self.tests, cycle(self.factory.slaves.values())): slave.tests.append(test)`, and then `self.tests = []`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the common gotcha of how loop variables and closures work in Python.  Consider this example:

```
>>> def f(n):
...     print n
... 
>>> fs = []
>>> for i in range(3):
...     fs.append(lambda: f(i))
... 
>>> fs[0]()
2
>>> fs[1]()
2
>>> fs[2]()
2
>>>
```

Comment: To clarify, the issue is in the loop inside `construct_list`.